# MS Access query from VB6 too long?

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I perform a query on an Access 2010 DB from a VB6 application. The SQL looks like that:

```
SELECT *, NetPrice AS Price 
FROM Products 
WHERE Len(ProductName)<>0 AND ProductID IN (1,5,8,13);
```

The following Code performs the query:

```
Set ResultRecordset = myDataBase.OpenRecordset(SqlCode, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

So far, everything is fine, but when the Number of the IDs in the List increses to about 50, then the ResultRecordset is `Nothing`. I have found some limitations for Access [here](http://www.databasezone.com/techdocs/acclimit.html), but I am far below the values provided there (1 Table, 200 characters query length, no nested subqueries,...). Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the query is not executed (is there any error or just returns wrong data?) if run from the VB. Have you tried to run it as a normal query, in main Access window?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but I think your `ProductID IN (1,5,8,13 /* ... and some 50 more ... */)` could hit the 50 Subqueries limit in the query that will actually be executed.

Comment: @Vocitus: Good point. I tried it and it works in Access! In VB6,I get no error message, but the Recordset is Nothing.

Comment: @Filburt: Possible, but with the previous said, this is more likely a problem of VB6-Access interaction.

Comment: The "normal query" (I don't know the proper name) has other (larger) limitations than VB. You can try to prepare a query, name it say `MyQuery` and run from the VB something like `SELECT * FROM MyQuery`, try if it works.

Comment: That's a ridiculous WHERE clause. Create another table with the 50+ product IDs and just INNER JOIN on it to filter the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
SqlCode="SELECT *, NetPrice AS Price FROM Products WHERE Len(ProductName)<>0"
Set TempRecordset = myDataBase.OpenRecordset(SqlCode, dbOpenSnapshot)
TempRecordset.Filter="ProductID IN (1,2,..,50)"
Set ResultRecordset=TempRecordset.OpenRecordset
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Filburt is actually more on target with your IN (some 50 in the list) part of the query.  I know that in FoxPro (and reaching back on this one), it too supports the IN() clause.  However, the IN functionality was only designed to accept up to 20 parameters in the list.  If you wanted to do more than that, you needed to split it into multiple IN() statements with OR between each... such as

```
where
   ProductID IN ( 1, 2, 20, 32, ...)
   OR ProductID IN (46, 50, 52, ...)
```

By splitting them MIGHT be the what you are running in to.

Comment: *I know you are working with VB, but believe it to be the same as in C#.* VB6 is not VB .NET, `dbOpenSnapshot` suggests DAO not ADO and definitely not ADO .NET.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, although it may be DAO, if the underlying handling is a limitation of the IN() operation it could be easily tested to confirm by splitting it up.

Comment: Yes, but there's no using statement or IDisposable equivalent in VB6.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, removed context of USING and try/catch... the underlying issue of splitting the IN() was more important though.

Comment: I tried it - unfortunately no luck. Thanks anyway for the idea, it seems to point to the right direction. Do you know if one can merge several Recordsets in VB6?

Comment: @PeterStock... No, don't know about merging record sets.  However, when dealing with DataAdapter and DataTables, if you run a query multiple times, it just keeps appending records into the dataset result.  You could try it and see if that has similar behavior.

Comment: @DRapp DataAdapter and DataTable are .NET again. I know that everything was much easier if only I could work in .NET, but I can't. I'll try to find some old VB6 documentation on DAO...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the UNION ALL operator in your query so that the query you send to Access is something like this:

```
SELECT *, NetPrice AS Price 
FROM Products 
WHERE Len(ProductName)<>0 AND ProductID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Union All

SELECT *, NetPrice AS Price 
FROM Products 
WHERE Len(ProductName)<>0 AND ProductID IN (10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
```

This should allow your query to run faster too, assuming your ProductID column is indexed.